# iptables forward all traffic to interface

Tags: iptables

I have two interfaces `eth1` and `eth0`. I want all traffic on `eth0`to  be forwarded to `eth1`. I created an iptable rule like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 0/0 -i eth0 -p tcp -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

But this doesn't work. Is this the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you haven't already enabled forwarding in the kernel, do so.

- Open `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
- Then execute `$ sudo sysctl -p`

Add the following rules to `iptables`

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth1 -j MASQUERADE  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

All of the forwarded traffic will traverse the FORWARD chain.  To filter  packets you'll now have to create rules on that chain specifying which interface is incoming/outgoing instead of using the INPUT/OUTPUT chains.