# Iptables FORWARD chain traffic not seen by tcpdump

Tags: linux, debian, networking, iptables, tcpdump

I have a bare metal running Ubuntu server 16.04 with KVM and 3 NIC's that are connected by bridges br1, br2 and br3 to a guest VM running also Ubuntu server 16.04.

The first NIC - br1 - is connected to the internet and it's router address is defined as the default gateway for the guest.

I have a code running on my guest that needs to listen to the packets received by br2 and br3, the code should listen to 1 NIC only,

I tried forwarding the traffic from en2 (the name of the guest NIC that is bridged via br2) to en3 (the same with br3) by [following this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126595/iptables-forward-all-traffic-to-interface):

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
uncomment net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

sudo sysctl -p
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface en3 -j MASQUERADE  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface en2 --out-interfac en3 -j ACCEPT
```

Yet there is nothing recorded when using `sudo tpcdump -i en3` and send a ping message to NIC2 (while if I run `sudo tpcdump -i en2` i can see the ping messages)

What am I missing here? Is there a better way for me to get my desired result (that my code will listen to 1 NIC and get both NIC's trafic) ?

Answer (score 5):

To listen specifically to the forwarded traffic, it is better to create a `nflog` rule/interface.

[Taking traffic dumps on Linux](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/CorrectTrafficDump)

So you will create a `nflog` interface:

```
sudo iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -j NFLOG --nflog-group 6
```

and then listen to it:

```
sudo tcpdump -s 0 -n -i nflog:6
```

> The solution to the problem, is to use the nflog interface in the
>   iptables framework, to get exactly the packets we are interested in.
>
> nflog rules log to a kernel internal multicast group, which is
>   identified by an integer in the 0 - 2^16-1 range. Only the part of the
>   datagram that the framework sees will be captured. For iptables that
>   is an IPv4 packet.
>
> Using nflog to dump packets forces you to use a special interface
>   syntax for tcpdump and wireshark. You must use nflog:groupnumber as
>   interface.
>
> Because nflog rules are normal iptables rules, the rules need a proper
>   match and target part so you get exactly the traffic you want. You
>   also must put the rule into the correct place for it to get the
>   packets you're interested in.

Comment: hi, seems like i am still missing something, i tried running those 2 commands and could not get ping packets when listening as you wrote, i tried adding to the first command '--in-interface en2' and still cant get see the ping packates

Comment: @MatanLevy It might be a better way, out of home, will get back to you tomorrow

Comment: tomorrow never dies.. :) I also have this issue and get error: `tcpdump: NFLOG link-layer type filtering not implemented`

Comment: @MladenB. The answer is from 2016, iptables is now a shim for a new implementation.