# iptables forward some devices to different interfaces based on source IP

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, vpn, iproute

I'm trying to expand further on a recent question I had asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620323/iptables-route-for-returning-incoming-traffic-back-out-of-originating-interfac/620357?noredirect=1#comment1160355_620357) (and was helped) based on this tutorial: https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-VPN-Gateway/#step5.

Using a Raspberry PI as a VPN box I've applied the following ip tables to route traffic over a VPN interface (nordlynx) with the source IP address of **192.168.4.26**, and back out the same interface and this works perfectly.

Currently I'm using 1 interface for input / output (eth0), and the VPN is provided by NordVPN (nordlynx is the name of the vpn interface).

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o nordlynx -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o nordlynx -s 192.168.4.26 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i nordlynx -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT      
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

My issue is any IP address that does not get forwarded over the nordlynx is no longer working. I tried to test by forwarding another device IP address: **192.168.4.51** back out of the eth0 interface so that it doesn't have to go through the VPN but it does not work:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0 -s 192.168.4.51 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.4.51 -j ACCEPT
```

I understand that maybe I should be using `iproute2` for this? I've tried adding these ip rules and routes but still nothing:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.4.51 table 200
ip route add default via 192.168.4.1 dev eth0 table 200
ip route flush cache
```

Is this because regardless of the ip rule / route it's being blocked by iptables rules? I'm a little confused here so any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong would be a big help.

****EDIT:****

```
                                  +--------------+                               
                                  |              |                               
                                  |  ISP MODEM   |                               
                                  |              |                               
                                  +--------------+                               
                                         |                                       
                                         |                                       
                       +------------------------------------+                    
                       |                                    |                    
                       |            MAIN ROUTER             |                    
                       |            192.168.4.1             |                    
                       |                                    |                    
                       +------------------------------------+                    
                           |              |               |                      
                           |              |               |                      
             +----------------+   +--------------+   +---------------+           
             |                |   |              |   |               |           
             |    MACBOOK 1   |   | RASPBERRY Pi |   |   MACBOOK 2   |           
             |  192.168.4.26  |   | 192.168.4.63 |   | 192.168.4.51  |           
             |                |---|              |---|               |           
             +----------------+   +--------------+   +---------------+           
                  ---                                         ---                
                     \---                                 ---/                   
                         \---                         ---/                       
                             \---                 ---/                           
                                 \--           --/                               
                MANUALLY SET ROUTER ADDRESS OF DEVICES TO RASPBERRY Pi           
                                  (192.168.4.63)
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip rule show
0:  from all lookup local 
32762:  from 192.168.4.51 lookup vpnbypass 
32763:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0 
32764:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820 
32765:  from all to 192.154.196.27 lookup main 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep

200 vpnbypass
```

Once the VPN is started, the following IPtables are set by NordVPN for Linux app (wireguard protocol):

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.154.196.27/32 -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.154.196.27/32 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p udp -m udp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o nordlynx -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i nordlynx -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.154.196.27/32 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.154.196.27/32 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p udp -m udp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your network topology? 192.168.4.26 is your local ip address on RPi and 192.168.4.51 is another PC behind RPi?

And please, copy and paste output from this commands:

```
ip rule show
cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
ip route show table xyz (for every table xyz form ip rule show command above or table name from rt_tables file)
```

Comment: Hi there, I've edited my post with a network diagram. Local IP address on RPi is 192.168.4.63 and 192.168.4.51 & 192.168.4.26 are IP's of other PC's on the network. I'd like for one of those PC's to use the VPN, and another one to not use the VPN.  (Essentially I'd like to be able to control enabling / disabling vpn on demand without needing to change network settings on the device each time back to the main router).

Original source for the setup is here: https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-VPN-Gateway/#step5

Comment: OK. What vpn service have you on tun0 device on RPi? Give mi a output from ip route show table vpnbypass.

Comment: And please, you have a two eth devices on RPi connected to internet? One for your vpn service and one for pure internet access? What is name of device for vpn service and what is name of device for pure internet access? Give me a ip route show output.